# Carrier density in topological insulators

Tags: topological-insulators

I'm currently doing my master thesis in physics, studying Topological Insulators. 
For the study of Shubnikov-de Haas oscillations visible in the magnetoresistance, it is usual to perform a Landau level (LL) fan diagram. The fitting yields values for the phase factor of the oscillations and the slope allows to determine the Fermi wave vector and, consequently, the carrier density. This is what I'm currently interested in. 
Ando (*J. Phys. Soc. Jpn 82 (2013)*) says that for a topological 2D surface, the carrier density and Fermi vector are related by:
$n_{2D}=1/(2\pi)^2\pi k_{F}^2$ 
It is said that this should be multiplied by 2 if the surface states doesn't have a topological origin (which would lead to the well known relation used in semiconductors...). My question is why should we not take into account the spin degeneracy in topological surfaces? 
Is it possibly due to the lifting of the degeneracy by the spin-orbit coupling anywhere but the TRIMs?
Thank you for any help.